# Open Files in Browser instead of downloading (including files like .doc, .xls etc)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am using Java Rest APIs to upload files in my project. Based on the configuration my files either goes into **s3 bucket, google drive, one drive** or even in **local file system** (in the same machine where my application is running). During download again I am making an ajax call which returns the file in response with **Content Disposition header attachment;** and browser downloads the file irrespective of its format.  I want an option to view these files in the **browser** instead of downloading it directly. How can I do that ? (Especially formats like doc,xls etc)

Comment: Try removing the `Content-Disposition` header, or set it to `inline`...

Comment: That way it works for pdf files, my main concern is to show other formats like doc or xls files

Comment: If it is `inline` (that is the default) the browser downloads the file, and ask the OS to open it, unless special treatment is built into the browser for the file's MIME-type. (Like PDF.) So, as what happens with the downloaded file depends on the clients browser and OS settings, installed programs, etc...

Comment: Jerry, all browsers I'm using are simply unable to directly open files like `doc`. Browsers usually open `html`, `css` and many image files. They also tend to open plain text files of any kind without a hassle, because that's what `html` or `css` files are. Many modern browsers now also open `pdf` (either natively or through plugins). Proprietary, binary files like `doc` on the other hand? I don't think so.

Comment: Is there some plugins which I can use for the same ? One suggestion I got was to use. https://products.office.com/en-IN/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=2cf6c50f-72ad-4c50-b25a-f1b5ec3d5e94. But for this to work I need to give public access to the file (I am saving files in s3 with private access)

Comment: When user clicks on view document, I am copying the file into an s3 bucket which is public with an expiration of one day and opening the file through https://products.office.com/en-IN/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=2cf6c50f-72ad-4c50-b25a-f1b5ec3d5e94 . Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no client-side libraries exist that can open .doc, .docs, .xls in browser. There is a way to render render your files using browser is to use **Google Documents' Viewer** or **Microsoft Office 365 viewer** via an `<iframe>`. Using this inside an `<iframe>` you can open your file in side your browser but can not edit.

**Google Documents' Viewer inside `<iframe>`**

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/path/to/your/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

**Google Documents' Viewer clickable link `<a>`**

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/path/to/your/document.doc&embedded=true">Open your doc file</a>
```

**Microsoft Office 365 viewer `<iframe>`**

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://example.com/path/to/your/document.doc' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: When I give my rest url it doesn't work. The url which I am giving is a GET request which when opened directly in browser downloads the file if user session is active in my application

Comment: Can we use byte array instead of url or blob url

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't have any built-in way to view Word docs so unless the user has configured their browser to open it with some plugin (which 99% of the world hasn't done), the browser will prompt them to download the file.

However, if you only need to display the Word Document, but don't need to edit it, you can use Google Documents' Viewer via an  to display a remotely hosted .doc/.docx.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://url-of-the-file&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

you can generate [temporary URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html) for your s3 documents by keeping them private.

if you are interested in giving users privilege to edit them online then you can go with any tool like [onlyoffice](https://www.onlyoffice.com/)

Comment: The problem we are facing is signed URL is not working with MS Office 365 viewer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59798131/583875