# Amazon S3 Signed Url is not working with Office Web Apps Viewer (encodeURIComponent not working)

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, office365, ms-office

I am trying to embed  'Office Web Apps Viewer' with iframe tag to show spreadsheet preview on my website. I tried  with encodeURIComponent for encoding the url but its showing "we are fetching your file" loading bar but nothing happens. thanks in advance.

```
const originalUrl ="https://exampleDomain.amazonaws.com/Folder/Filename.xlsx?algorithm=algorithmName&credential=region&date=date&expires=time&token=encryptedToken&signature=encryptedSignature&headers=example"
const encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(originalUrl);
const iFrameUrl = `https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${encodedUrl}`;
<iframe title="l" src={iFrameUrl} style={{ maxHeight: 'auto', maxWidth: 'auto'}} />
```

Note: the above code work with google docs by replacing src = https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=yourUrl&embedded=true

Comment: Have you checked your browser console to see if there's anything to see, there?  Have you checked the S3 bucket logs to see if perhaps an access attempt is occurring but with mangled parameters?

Comment: We are also facing this issue. signed s3 URLs are not working. Anyone has a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem but using Google Cloud Storage. I believe the Office Web Apps viewer simply can cope with the URLs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815774/flutter-web-display-microsoft-documents-firebase

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into this issue also, so I've done some digging. It appears to be failing if there are any `GET` variables in the URL. An idea jumped to mind about using a URL redirect to mask the S3 URL and **this worked**. (I used [bit.ly](https://bit.ly) to create a redirect without any `GET` variables)

Obviously, this isn't a brilliant solution but it does work. If you own the server you could create your own backend for generating these URLs that don't contain `GET` variables.

You could then generate URLs in the format:

`https://example.com/api/s3request/s3_domain_path/get_param_1/getparam_2/get_param_3/etc/`

Which will return a redirect to:

`https://s3_domain_path?X-Amz-Security-Token=get_param_1&X-Amz-Algorithm=get_param_2`

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same error, I fixed it by using this method `encodeURIComponent(url)`.

**The Code:**

```
let url = 'url_signed';
const URLOFFICE = `https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=`;
let urlIframe = `${URLOFFICE}${encodeURIComponent(url)}`;
$("#bodyViewFile").html(`<embed src="${urlIframe}" width="100%" height="550px" />`);
$("#modalViewFile").modal("show");
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35708164)